# is performed in this sentence adjective to studies?

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if performed in "based on studies performed in our lab" is adjective of the verb?
is the structure correct?

Comment: And what do you think is the verb? The adjective forms of the noun "performance" are:  *performable*, *performing* and *performed*

Answer (score 2):

> ... *based on studies* [*performed in our lab*]

The structure is fine. "Performed" is not an adjective here but a past participle verb form.

"Performed in our lab" is a subordinate, past-participial clause modifying "studies". It has the same meaning as the relative clause in "based on studies [that were performed in our lab]". The clause is a bare passive, as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase, as in "... performed in our lab by technicians".

"Performed" doesn't normally occur as an adjective, though it is found in the compound adjective "well-performed", as in "a well-performed concert", where it is based on the active use of the past participle "performed".

Comment: I don't think you've explicitly pointed it out, but *based on studies* is ALSO a *subordinate, past-participial clause*. All the OP has given us here is a "fragment", not a complete "sentence".